# What's wrong with GitHub?

Tags: github

Anyone else recently experiencing problems pushing to GitHub repos?  I keep receiving errors when I try:

```
error: RPC failed; result=35, HTTP code = 0
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
Everything up-to-date
```

or

```
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/sr-murthy/TPP.git/': Server aborted the SSL handshake
```

Is this some kind of DDoS attack?

Comment: GitHub is being DDoSed, supposedly by the Chinese government. Various stories have been posted - check Slashdot.

Answer (score 1):

This error may be because of the open ssl site down.
Please do operation Once again? If you still facing issue You can disable the sslVerfication for you Debugging Purpose.so that you may come to some conclusion.

Change it in User Settings like `http.sslVerify=false` (If you are using eclipse `window--?Preferences-->git-->configuration-->User Settings`)